# Access private/Internal functions of solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethers.js

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract C {
   string internal secret= "secret data";
   
   function x() internal returns (uint) {
      return 10;
   }
}
```

**Accessing Internal Variable:**

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt('0x6260319bcbcbf33f84397ae0000e49b0f50ee075', 0, (e, v) => console.log(web3.toAscii(v)));
```

So far what i understand is we can access Internal Variables through storage,
What i want to know is if there is a way to also access Internal *Functions*, by layout i understand that they dont exist in storage section of EVM. so if we can access them, how ?

Comment: Where do you want to access the internal functions? In your frontend?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg in frontend, or any script, basically just wanna invoke the internal function.

Comment: well "any script" is a bit vague. There are development contexts in which you can access the internal functions, but I will assume that you're not referring to those.

Comment: Basically it is not possible to call internal or private functions from any frontend context.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg can you give a elaborate reason why private/internal variables are accessible but functions are not?

Comment: private/ internal variables are not accessible either.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg you can try this code ```web3.eth.getStorageAt('0x6260319bcbcbf33f84397ae0000e49b0f50ee075', 0, (e, v) => console.log(web3.toAscii(v)));
``` to access this internal variable

Comment: what I meant is that private/ internal variables are not accessible via a getter because Solidity doesn't create getters for them. Of course you can read anything manually from the contract's storage - everything stored on Ethereum is public.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg so is there a way to also call internal function? in such a manner ?